# tkinter change background colors menu option

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am wondering on how I can create a change bgcolor menu as once clicked, my code doesn't work.
Here a code and Sorry for my bad english.

```
from tkinter import*

def bg(color):
    root.config(bg=color)

root = Tk()
menubar=Menu(root)
bgmenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="bgcolor",menu=bgmenu)
bgmenu.add_command(label="Indian red",command = bg('indianred'))
bgmenu.add_command(label="Powder blue",command = bg('powderblue'))
bgmenu.add_command(label="Grey",command = bg('grey'))
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*

def bg(color):
    root.config(bg=color)

root = Tk()
menubar=Menu(root)
bgmenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="bgcolor",menu=bgmenu)
bgmenu.add_command(label="Indian red",command = lambda: bg('indianred'))
bgmenu.add_command(label="Powder blue",command = lambda:bg('powderblue'))
bgmenu.add_command(label="Grey",command =lambda:bg('grey'))
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

use the lambda function for the button's command when you want to call it along with an argument